# Is there a performance cost when entering TRY/CATCH blocks?

Tags: try-catch, abap

The following is a question about the performance of the ABAP TRY/CATCH construct. In particular, it is not about throwing or catching exceptions.

Is there a performance cost when entering TRY/CATCH blocks? For example, if there is a loop and the TRY could be outside and inside the loop body, would there be a performance difference between the two options?

Again, it is not about throwing or catching exceptions, it is about entering and leaving TRY/CATCH blocks.

Comment: I never heard of any performance issue.

Comment: There is an overhead when exceptions are thrown but one cannot speak of an performance issue here. It is just the standard cost of using them. Also remeber that the exceptions are not designed for the standard flow of control e.g. for doing such things as `GOTO` statements. They are after all called _exceptions_ which mean they should be used for extraordinary situations.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as "opinion-based". There are a lot of objective things that can be said about the performance implications of exceptions - both those that happen and those that don't happen - and those statements can be proven or disproven by doing performance tests.

Comment: @Philipp You can always use the power of Stackoverflow's democracy and vote to reopen this question. :)

Comment: @Jagger I already did half an hour ago.

Comment: It can even be proven by looking at the bytecode that's available in the ABAP system (e.g. inside loop and outside loop)

Comment: @Jagger This democracy is limited to 3,000 reputation though :)

Comment: @peterulb only voters that are experienced enough are allowed. :)

Comment: I should have made more clear that the question is about the TRY/CATCH construct itself, not its use when throwing/catching exceptions. So, asked differently, if a statement in a loop body can throw an exception, is there a difference between placing the TRY outside and inside the LOOP.